# \cite[page]{book} inside \caption[...]{...}

Tags: captions, citing, natbib

Is it somehow possible to put a citation including page specification, as in `\cite[page]{book}`, inside the list-of-figures-relevant caption of a figure, i.e. `\caption[*HERE*]{...}`?

I can do

```
\caption[\protect\cite{book}]{other text}
```

but

```
\caption[\protect\cite[page]{book}]{other text}
```

yields `book] other text` as the caption in the first run and produces an error "Argument of \NAT@@cite has an extra }" in the second LaTeX run.

I'm using pdfLaTeX and natbib.

Comment: LaTeX mistakes the bracket after `page` for the closing bracket of the optional argument; `\caption[{\protect\cite[page]{book}}]{other text}`

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, that was quick and easy! Could've thought of that myself... Care to post that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: note that citations in lists-of-*, toc, etc., play havoc with unsrt-type biblio styles.  i think there's a faq answer about that...

Comment: Side note (if anyone come across this later, question is old) `\cite` is already robust, so you don't need `\protect`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The scanning of an optional argument (in brackets, `[` and `]`) works in a slight different way than the scanning of a mandatory argument (in braces, `{` and `}`); TeX counts the braces, but doesn't do the same for brackets. So, with your input, the optional argument that is seen is

```
\protect\cite[page
```

that is, everything from `[` to the first `]` (which is balanced with respect to *braces*). In order to avoid this problem, brackets inside an optional argument must be "masked" with braces:

```
\caption[{\protect\cite[page]{book}}]{other text}
```

The argument cannot have unbalanced *braces*, so the bracket after `page` doesn't end it, in this case.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Out of curiosity: Do you know the reasoning behind the different behavior for optional vs mandatory arguments / [] vs {}?

Comment: The balancing of braces is built in in TeX; optional arguments in LaTeX are treated in a rather different way.

Comment: @ egreg, I want to congratulate you for such a complete answer! Even though it seems something simple, this is the kind of question to be expected in Tex.SX